# Skipping item from loop

Tags: ansible

I want ansible loop to skip first only the first item on a list > item - a

the task looks like:

```
- name: create project sub-directory
  win_file:
    path: '{{ projects_dir }}\{{ project_name }}\{{ item }}'
  state: directory
  loop: '{{ sub_directories }}'
```

vars file looks like:

```
sub_directories:
 - a
 - b
 - c
 - d
```

I want the loop to skip item - a so that it creates only b, c and d subdirectories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use index. See [Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

```
loop: "{{ sub_directories[1:] }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use loop control in ansible

```
- name: create project sub-directory
  win_file:
    path: '{{ projects_dir }}\{{ project_name }}\{{ item }}'
  state: directory
  when: my_idx != 0
  loop: '{{ sub_directories }}'
  loop_control:
     index_var: my_idx
```

Comment: Thanks. I will go for Vladimir solution as it is simple.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is another solution specifically for special handling of the first item:

Set `loop_control` to `extended` and then utilize the `ansible_loop.first` variable set by ansible for the first item of the loop.

This requires Ansible 2.8 or later.